# Why does my picture not fill the parent block

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

This is my FOP:

```
<fo:block background-color="blue">
<fo:instream-foreign-object background-color="yellow" content-width="0.8cm" content-height="0.3cm" scaling="non-uniform" vertical-align="middle">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
        <g>
            <path d="m 0 0 l 200 0 l -50 100 l -150 0 z"/>
            <text x="140" y="80"
                style="font-family: Times New Roman;
                font-size: 80px;
                text-align:end;
                text-anchor:end;
                fill: white;">12</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>
```

This render like this with appache FOP version 2:

[image: fop.pdf]

Why does the SVG not fill the parent block?

Comment: FOP describes itself as "a print formatter driven by XSL formatting objects (XSL-FO)" (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/), and your markup also works with other formatters besides FOP.

Answer (score 1):

The `content-width="0.8cm" content-height="0.3cm" scaling="non-uniform"` forces the image to be 0.8cm wide and 0.3cm tall.

If you want to fill the width, change it to `content-width="scale-to-fit" width="100%"`:

```
<fo:block background-color="blue" font-size="0">
    <fo:instream-foreign-object background-color="yellow" content-width="scale-to-fit" width="100%">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <g>
                <path d="m 0 0 l 200 0 l -50 100 l -150 0 z"/>
                <text x="140" y="80"
                    style="font-family: Times New Roman;
                    font-size: 80px;
                    text-align:end;
                    text-anchor:end;
                    fill: white;">12</text>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: If your problem is just the blue above and below the SVG, you might be more interested in the `font-size="0"` as a way to remove the 'half-leading' (see, e.g., https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#line-height) that is the reason for the blue above and below the line.

Comment: Since you are using `font-size="0"` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020129/xsl-fo-why-my-block-overflow-page-body, consider accepting this answer.