# xsl-fo : why my block overflow page body

Tags: xsl-fo

need help please.
This is part of my test.fo. Il think problem comes from float object but i have no idea why :

```
....
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
     ...
     <fo:block line-height="1.2">
        <fo:block text-align-last="justify"
                  font-family="MTTMilano-Bold"
                  color="rgb(38,68,160)"
                  font-size="10pt">
           <fo:inline>
            title
        </fo:inline>
           <fo:leader leader-pattern="space"/>
           <fo:inline text-align="end"
                      font-family="UsherwoodStd-Book"
                      color="rgb(0,0,0)"
                      font-size="9pt"/>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block space-after="0.35cm">
           <fo:float>
              <fo:block font-size="0">
                 <fo:instream-foreign-object content-width="0.8cm" padding-before="0.06cm">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                         width="140"
                         height="40"
                         viewBox="0 0 140 40">
                       <g>
                          <path d="m 0 0 l 140 0 l -10 40 l -130 0 z" fill="rgb(167,165,166)"/>
                          <text fill="white"
                                font-family="MTTMilano-Bold"
                                font-size="45pt"
                                text-anchor="end"
                                x="125"
                                y="35">II.</text>
                       </g>
                    </svg>
                 </fo:instream-foreign-object>
              </fo:block>
           </fo:float>
           <fo:block start-indent="0.9cm" text-align-last="justify">
              <fo:inline text-align-last="justify"
                         font-family="MTTMilano-Bold"
                         color="rgb(38,68,160)"
                         font-size="9pt">title</fo:inline>
              <fo:leader leader-pattern="space"/>
              <fo:inline text-align="end"
                         font-family="UsherwoodStd-Book"
                         color="rgb(0,0,0)"
                         font-size="9pt">34</fo:inline>
           </fo:block>
           <fo:block clear="both"/>
        </fo:block>
 ...
```

and the PDF generated [pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJrU1.png). 
Why my last title "c." on page 1 overflow the page body ? 
thanks

Comment: It's not obvious why your block is not breaking.  Is there something that contains all of the `fo:block`.  Are you using the `keep-together` property anywhere?

Comment: Separately, it's also not obvious why you are using `fo:float`.  Look at `fo:list-block`, `fo:list-item`, `fo:list-item-label`, and `fo:list-item-body`.  See the examples at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e12374 and https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/.  It seems to me that you could put your SVG images in the `fo:list-item-label` of an `fo:list-item` for much the same effect.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE] to help answerers perform better.